# "Object required" - path string unrecognized in windows scripting file

Tags: windows-scripting

I'm writing a wsf that opens a csv, reads the contents and prints them like so:

```
<job id="Test_Script">
   <script language="VBScript">

    Dim objFSO, strSourcePath, strSourceFile, objInFile, strData    

    Set strSourcePath = "C:\test\ERACSV\"
    Set strSourceFile = "Payments.csv"
    Set objFSO        = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")   
    Set objInFile     = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strSourcePath & strSourceFile, 1, False)
    Set strData       = objInFile.ReadAll
    objInFile.Close

    WScript.Echo strData
   </script>
</job>
```

I keep getting this weird error:

```
Script:  C:\Users\myuser\openCSV.wsf
Line:    4
Char:    4
Error:   Object Required '[string: "C:\test\ERACSV"]'
Code:    800A01A8
Source:  Microsoft VBScript runtime error
```

It seems weird because why is the object it requiring a string I've already defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `Set` in VBScript is only for "object-types" (COM Objects, etc), but `String` values are not "objects" (as far as VBScript is concerned), so don't use `Set`.

  - You can either remove the `Set` keyword but otherwise keep the assignment statement as-is, or altenatively use the `Let` keyword instead of `Set`: `Let` is for non-object values (including Strings, but also Integers and Doubles).
- In VBScript, when calling a `Function` (or COM Method) that *returns a value* you need to specify parentheses, you only omit the parentheses when calling a `Sub` (i.e. a `void` function or method) ([unless you're using the `Call` statement](https://www.devguru.com/content/features/kb/kb100222.html)), in this case `TextStream.ReadAll()` returns a `String` value.
- Use the named-constant `ForReading` instead of the magic-number literal `1`.
- You also should add `Option Explicit` at the first-line of your script, otherwise VBScript won't care about variable declarations (indeed: `objOutFile` is declared, but `objInFile` is what's actually used....)

```
<job id="Test_Script">
   <script language="VBScript">

    Option Explicit

    Dim objFSO, strSourcePath, strSourceFile, objInFile, strData    

    Let strSourcePath = "C:\test\ERACSV\"
    Let strSourceFile = "Payments.csv"
    Set objFSO        = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")   
    Set objInFile     = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strSourcePath & strSourceFile, ForReading, False)
    Let strData       = objInFile.ReadAll()
    objInFile.Close

    WScript.Echo strData
   </script>
</job>
```